# Forward subprocess stdout does not work when stdout is redirected to a file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem forwarding the stdout of a subprocess to stdout of the current process.

This is my MWE caller code (runner.py):

```
import sys
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "test.py"], stdout=sys.stdout)
time.sleep(10)
p.terminate()
```

and here is the content of the callee test.py:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Heartbeat"
```

The following will work and print all the heartbeats to the console:

```
python runner.py
```

However, the following does not work, the output text file remains empty (using Python 2.7):

```
python runner.py > test.txt
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: `shell=True` might fix it.

Comment: @zondo No, I do not want to have the shell commands included

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the standard output is a TTY (a terminal), `sys.stdout` is line-buffered by default: each line you print is immediately written to the TTY.

But when the standard output is a file, then `sys.stdout` is block-buffered: data is written to the file only when a certain amount of data gets printed. By using `p.terminate()`, you are killing the process before the buffer is flushed.

Use `sys.stdout.flush()` after your `print` and you'll be fine:

```
import sys
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Heartbeat"
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

If you were using Python 3, you could also use the `flush` argument of the `print` function, like this:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Heartbeat", flush=True)
```

Alternatively, you can also set up a handler for `SIGTERM` to ensure that the buffer is flushed when `p.terminate()` gets called:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sys.stdout.flush)
```

Comment: 1- it is error-prone (and inefficient) to call `sys.stdout.flush()` manually all over your program. You can unbuffer stdout for the whole process instead 2- `signal(signal.SIGTERM, sys.stdout.flush)` won't work. You might mean `signal(signal.SIGTERM, lamba *a: (sys.stdout.flush(), sys.exit(-signal.SIGTERM)))` instead. Though it might be simpler, to [call `p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` instead of `p.terminate()` in the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35819206/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: flushing output is actually *the* way. You don't have to trust me: look at `ping`, `tail` or every other tool in your system that writes output periodically

Comment: Why do you think `grep` has `--line-buffered` parameter? Why doesn't it flush after each line by default as you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to force flushes by doing `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print, but this would quickly become cumbersome. Since you know you're running Python, it is possible to force Python to unbuffered mode - either with `-u` switch or `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py'], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

or

```
import os
# force all future python processes to be unbuffered
os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = '1'

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'test.py'])
```

Comment: you could pass `env=dict(os.environ, PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1)` to `Popen()` to avoid affecting other python processes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `stdout=sys.stdout` unless `sys.stdout` uses a different file descriptor than the one that `python` executable has started with. C stdout fd is inherited by default: you don't need to do anything in order for the child process to inherit it.

[As @Andrea Corbellini said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800917/4279), if the output is redirected to a file then `python` uses a block-buffering mode and `"Heartbeat"*10` (usually) is too small to overflow the buffer.
I would expect that `python` flushes its internal stdout buffers on exit but it doesn't do it on `SIGTERM` signal (generated by the `.terminate()` call).
To allow the child process to exit gracefully, use `SIGINT` (Ctrl+C) instead of `p.terminate()`:

```
p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

In that case `test.py` will flush the buffers and you'll see the output in `test.txt` file. Either discard stderr or catch `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the child.

If you want to see the output while the child process is still running then run `python -u`, to disable buffering or set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` envvar to change the behavior of all affected `python` processes as [@Antti Haapala suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801080/4279).

Note: your parent process may also buffer the output. If you don't flush the buffer in time then the output printed *before* `test.py` is even started may appear *after* its output in the `test.txt` file. The buffers in the parent and the child processes are independent. Either flush buffers manually or make sure that an appropriate buffering mode is used in each process. See [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/4279)